# Ifdef conditional unexpected behavior

Tags: bash, makefile, conditional-compilation

I have a Makefile with command like this:

```
#Makefile
    hello:
        echo 'hello'
        echo $(TAG)
        ifdef TAG
              $(warning MYWARNING)
        else
              $(error MYERROR)
        endif
```

I use it like:

```
# make TAG='1.0' hello
```

I expect that command performs echo 'hello', then echo $(TAG) and $(warning MYWARNING) but I get:

```
Makefile:17: MYWARNING
Makefile:19: *** MYERROR.  Stop.
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's try some simpler cases(*).

```
hello:
    echo hello
    $(error MYERROR)
```

This produces:

```
Makefile:3: *** MYERROR.  Stop.
```

Notice that the `error` blocks the `echo`, even thought it comes afterward.

Now let's try something silly:

```
hello:
    ifdef TAG
```

The result is:

```
ifdef TAG
make: ifdef: No such file or directory
```

"ifdef TAG", *interpreted as a shell command,* makes no sense. And it is interpreted as a shell command because it's in a recipe and preceded by a TAB.

Now let's combine them:

```
hello:
    ifdef TAG
    $(error MYERROR)
```

The result is `Makefile:3: *** MYERROR.  Stop.` So the `error` obscures the fact that the `ifdef...` was incorrect.

Do we want a *shell* conditional, or a *Make* conditional? If we want to Make to act on it (with `error` or `warning`), then it must be a Make conditional, so we must not preceded it with a TAB:

```
hello:
ifdef TAG
    $(warning MYWARNING)
else
    $(error MYERROR)
endif
```

This works as intended.

(*) as you ought to have tried before you posted.